# RFC: ssh -X to run a java app on login via SHELL variable, security and other issues?

Tags: linux, ssh, security, java, xforwarding

I have a java application (not applet) which I run via a script which contains just this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/java -classpath /A/B.jar:/X/Y.jar MyApp.Go -p 1 -p 2 -p 3
```

This app, during initialisation, requires to read a lot of auxiliary files which live in the local disk along with the app. These files are a few gbytes. The app's GUI is simple: clicking on the main window (a map) a script is launched via `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`. The script will do some processing and output its result to a file. Which the app then reads and presents to a new window. The only button is for Quitting. No other user input, no file selectors.

I needed a solution in order to allow this app to be run remotely. That is: app+data reside on my linux-server and client needs to run it from their own computer, remotely. I would like to avoid sending the app over to the client. Not only because I want to hide the code (to avoid de-compilation) but also because those gbytes of local data need to be bundled as well - not practical.

I have looked at converting it into an applet but except from the fact that (most/all) browsers now don't support it, that applet must be run on the client's computer and all those data files would eventually need to be read from server and transfered over to where the applet is running+initialising, i.e. the client's computer. Not practical again.

I have also looked at some applications which convert java bytecode to javascript, claiming they give you something which runs in HTML5. This worked only for a toy app.

**RFC:**
Eventually I thought about creating a new user in my server whose SHELL would be pointing to the script which runs the java app (script above). I have allowed `X11Forwarding yes` in sshd's config at my server and told the linux-based clients to just do: `ssh -X abc@X.Y.Z.M` and the app would appear on their desktop. I also told the windows-based clients to install an X-server and do something similar. This tested well on linux (not tried on windows).

I am looking for comments on my approach, especially regarding security. I am comfortable on giving a client a limited account like this. But I would not like the client to find access to a shell in my server if the app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `exec` to your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/java -classpath /A/B.jar:/X/Y.jar MyApp.Go -p 1 -p 2 -p 3
```

This will cause the java process to replace the shell process running the script, instead of becoming a child process of the shell. That way, once the java process starts up, there will be no shell to return to, and if the java process dies for any reason, the login session will just end immediately.

Comment: thank you @telcoM for good suggestion. My server's host company is running some init scripts with a message-of-the-day and the likes on login. I wonder if by sending a CTRL-C somewhere within this init phase but before the java app sh script executes, could give me a shell. I tried a few times and it closes the connection. What do you think? But I am still doubtfull.

Comment: There are many ways to implement a message-of-the-day. If the hosting provider configures `sshd` to output it before the session actually begins, there should be no way to interrupt it. But of course if the hosting provider has tried to do something more fancy, and has implemented it poorly, it might be vulnerable to interruption.

Comment: i will take it up with them, thank you very much for your help.